# What is an accurate approximation and asymptotic for this function?

Tags: asymptotics, approximation

$$f(n)=\Bigg(1-\Big(1-\frac{1}{2^{n/2}}\Big)^n\Bigg)^{n^7}$$

I am interested in large $n$.
The number $7$ can be replaced by any fixed integer.

I have $$f(n)\rightarrow\Bigg(1-e^{-n2^{-n/2}}\Bigg)^{n^7}\rightarrow e^{-e^{-n2^{-n/2}}n^7}$$

Comment: What does that $\to$ mean? Convergence? The $n$ may not appear in the value of a limit where $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @wauzl asymptotic.

Answer (score 1):

For large $n$, $n2^{-n/2}<<1$ so the $e^{-x}\approx 1-x$ approximation works. Let's replace $7$ with $k$. We have $$\ln f = n^k\ln\left(1-\left(1-2^{-n/2}\right)^n\right)\approx n^k\ln\left(n2^{-n/2}\right)=n^k\left(-n\ln\sqrt{2}+\ln n\right).$$Hence$$f\approx n^{n^k}\sqrt{2}^{-n^{k+1}}.$$

Comment: looks wrong your $f$ blowsup. still blows up after edit.

Comment: Not sure it blows up.  The factor containing $\sqrt(2)$ has one higher "third level" exponent than the other, which should make it dominate as $n$ grows, and that factor goes to zero.

Comment: Let me put numbers in to that effect (can't put two paragraphs into one comment, sorry).  $n=8, k=7$ gives $8^{8^7}=2^{+6,291,456}$ but $(\sqrt2)^{8^{-8}}=2^{-8,388,608}$.